# Blinking motherboard power LED

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, desktop-computer

I was just rebuilding an old desktop PC to be used as a HTPC and the LED on the motherboard that indicates when there is power is blinking fairly rapidly. The only way I can get the machine to boot is to press the power button immediately after plugging it in, and even then I cannot make it into the BIOS.

The power supply has more than enough juice to power all of the components, and is from a reputable manufacturer.

The motherboard is an Asus and is about 4.5 years old.

Is my power supply hosed? Or is it my motherboard?

Comment: What's the brand/model of the motherboard?

Comment: Motherboard is an Asus; updated description.

Comment: Will attempt hooking up my desktop's PSU to it when I get the chance, but it won't be tonight.

Comment: Do any of the fans/disk spin? If not then its most probably is a PSU issue. If the fans/disks do spin then try booting with the bare essentials. Like Mobo + CPU + 1 RAM Stick + (GPU if no onboard available)